# Hash password in Prisma ORM

Tags: node.js, hash, prisma

How to properly and elegantly hash a password in Prisma ORM when creating a model object?

My `prisma/schema.prisma` file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String   @db.VarChar(100)
  username    String   @db.VarChar(100) @unique
  password    String   @db.Char(60) //<-I want this field to be hashed when created
  email       String   @db.VarChar(100) @unique
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  @@map("users")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to hash a password in Prisma ORM when creating/updating a model object.

1. Using middleware (is deprecated since version 4.16.0). For example:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

prisma.$use((params, next) => {
  if (params.model === 'User' && ['create', 'update'].includes(params.action) && params.args.data['password']) {
    params.args.data['password'] = bcrypt.hashSync(params.args.data['password'], 10)
  }
  return next(params)
})
```

See for details [Middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) section.

2. Using Prisma Client extension (is available from versions 4.16.0 and later). For example:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  query: {
    user: {
      $allOperations({ operation, args, query }) {
        if (['create', 'update'].includes(operation) && args.data['password']) {
          args.data['password'] = bcrypt.hashSync(args.data['password'], 10)
        }
        return query(args)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

See for details the following sections: [Extensions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions) and [`query`: Create custom Prisma Client queries](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/query).

In both cases, the usage will be the same:

```
prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Blasius Komarov',
    username: 'Justitingich',
    password: '123456',
    email: 'BlasiusKomarov@dayrep.com'
  }
})
  .then(model => console.log(model.password)) //<-'$2b$10$b7zPXhfnT9Rvww6u6Ca8z.kBtTiBT2pZ2slBNvQ1KUXxlC4S7P3uW'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash and encryption is not same. However you may be want to hash your password so that you can store user password securely in Database.

To do that you have to hash it from your js code, then you have to send the hash as a string and the `password` field will save the hash as a string only.

Your `prisma/schema.prisma` file should not contain limit of password characters. It should be like this.

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String   @db.VarChar(100)
  username    String   @db.VarChar(100) @unique
  password    String   // <- no password character limit
  email       String   @db.VarChar(100) @unique
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  @@map("users")
}
```

Hash password your password from your javascript code. You can use [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

An example is given below for plain nodejs.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const {PrismaClient} = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const saltRounds = 10;
const passwordToHash = 'my_password_123'; 
// you can use password character limit here at the time of getting the data from user


// Hash password with bcrypt and save to db
bcrypt.hash(passwordToHash, saltRounds, function(_err, hash) {
    // check error here
    // Then save password in DB with prisma
    (async(){
        prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                //... (give all other user data here)
                password: hash
            }
        })
    })().catch( (prismaError) => {console.log(prismaError)} )

});
```

To check a user is valid or not, you can use `bcrypt.compare` method.

```
async function checkUser(username, password) {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            username
        }
    })

    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if(match) {
        //login
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the note about encryption/hashing. I corrected my question.

Comment: why do you need to hash password by prisma? its an ORM which makes the database query easier. It has no functionality to hash password.